# How can I numactl membind a process inside Docker container?

Tags: python, linux, docker, virtualization, numa

I have an Intel Xeon Phi 64-core CPU with 16GB **on-chip memory** set as NUMA node 1.  I want to bind a process running inside a Docker container to this NUMA node, but it errors out:

```
root@Docker$ sudo numactl --membind 1 python script.py
Error: set_mempolicy: Operation not permitted
setting membind: Operation not permitted
```

I also tried to bind the entire Docker mothership to NUMA node 1, but no luck:

```
localhost$ sudo numactl --membind 1 docker run xyz /bin/bash
```

This doesn't give any error, but shows no utilization of on-chip memory.

My question is: How can I bind a process to NUMA node 1 successfully?  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Try granting the deceptively-named `CAP_SYS_NICE` capability to the container, which allows the process to "set CPU affinity for arbitrary processes" [[ref](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html)]:

```sh
docker run --cap-add SYS_NICE <other arguments>
```

This a safer approach than `--privileged` but should still enable what you need.

Answer (score 4):

1. You need to get which cpus belongs to 1 numa node:

   `$ lscpu | grep node1`

   `NUMA node1 CPU(s):     8-15,24-31`
2. Create cpuset for docker:

   `$ cgcreate -g cpuset:docker`

   `$ echo 8-15 > /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset/docker/cpuset.cpus`
3. If you want to run just certain containers on specific NUMA node:

   `cgcreate -g cpuset:my-cgroup`

   `echo 8-15 > /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset/my-cgroup/cpuset.cpus`
4. Docker allows to put new containers under a different cgroup:

   `docker run -it --rm --cgroup-parent=/my-cgroup/ ubuntu bash`

For more information see https://sthbrx.github.io/blog/2016/07/27/get-off-my-lawn-separating-docker-workloads-using-cgroups/ .

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue which got solved by creating a container using "**--privileged**" mode.

With this mode, we can bind mem and CPU nodes inside the container and use numa effectively.

**Use the below command:**

```
#docker run --privileged --name=test_numa --net=host -itd <image_id>
```

Comment: solved an issue regarding numa binding on cpus sharing the **same** numa node